# Counting, Averaging and Concatenating a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe in Pandas that contains a set of product reviews, for slightly different products from a selection of review websites. Each review is related to a product, with a numeric score. The reviews also have a text field containing the text of each review (quite a long field), and the name of the source site it was taken from.
E.g.

```
product    score    source    text
------------------------------------------
K3         4.0      site1     long-text
P2         2.0      site7     text
K3         3.0      site2     paragraph
i7         1.0      site4     review-text
P2         5.0      site2     more-text
K3         4.0      site5     texts-on-text
```

I want to group each product together in a new table, so that I can analyse how each product is being reviewed. I will eventually perform text analysis (POS tagging etc) to understand how each product is being reviewed.

I want to start by creating a new dataframe, grouping by 'product'. I want to count the number of reviews that each product has in column 'count'. There will be a column that calculates the average of the 'score' when grouped. There will also be a column which combines the text fields for each product, so that the review texts can be analysed as a whole rather than separately.
E.g.

```
product    mean_score    count     text_combined
---------------------------------------------------
K3         3.66          3         long-text, paragraph, texts-on-text
P2         3.5           2         text, more-text
i7         1.0           1         review-text
```

The 'source' column isn't required in this particular analysis, but I have included it just to show that there are other columns in the dataframe.

From this I can more easily break down text for each product, as opposed to individual reviews.

Thanks in advance Stack!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.groupby('product').agg({'score':'mean', 'source':'size', 'text': ', '.join})
#change order of columns, create column from index values 
df = df.reindex_axis(['score','source','text'], axis=1).reset_index()
#set new column names
df.columns = ['product','mean_score','count','text_combined']
print (df)
  product  mean_score  count                        text_combined
0      K3    3.666667      3  long-text, paragraph, texts-on-text
1      P2    3.500000      2                      text, more-text
2      i7    1.000000      1                          review-text
```

EDIT:

Solution with `dict` in output:

```
from collections import Counter

df = df.groupby('product')
       .agg({'score':'mean', 'product':'size', 'text': ', '.join, 'source': lambda x: [dict(Counter(x))]})
#change order of columns, create column from index values 
df = df.reindex_axis(['score','product','text', 'source'], axis=1)
       .rename_axis('a')
       .reset_index()
#set new column names
df.columns = ['product','mean_score','count','text_combined', 'count_sources']
df['L'] = pd.Series(df.values.tolist())
print (df)
  product  mean_score  count                        text_combined  \
0      K3    3.666667      3  long-text, paragraph, texts-on-text   
1      P2    3.500000      2                      text, more-text   
2      i7    1.000000      1                          review-text   

                            count_sources  \
0  [{'site1': 1, 'site2': 1, 'site5': 1}]   
1              [{'site7': 1, 'site2': 1}]   
2                          [{'site4': 1}]   

                                                   L  
0  [K3, 3.6666666666666665, 3, long-text, paragra...  
1  [P2, 3.5, 2, text, more-text, [{'site7': 1, 's...  
2          [i7, 1.0, 1, review-text, [{'site4': 1}]]
```

And solution with `tuples` in output:

```
from collections import Counter

df = df.groupby('product')
       .agg({'score':'mean', 'product':'size', 'text': ', '.join, 'source': lambda x: list(dict(Counter(x)).items())})
#change order of columns, create column from index values 
df = df.reindex_axis(['score','product','text', 'source'], axis=1)
       .rename_axis('a')
       .reset_index()

#set new column names
df.columns = ['product','mean_score','count','text_combined', 'count_sources']
df['L'] = pd.Series(df.values.tolist())
print (df)
  product  mean_score  count                        text_combined  \
0      K3    3.666667      3  long-text, paragraph, texts-on-text   
1      P2    3.500000      2                      text, more-text   
2      i7    1.000000      1                          review-text   

                          count_sources  \
0  [(site1, 1), (site2, 1), (site5, 1)]   
1              [(site7, 1), (site2, 1)]   
2                          [(site4, 1)]   

                                                   L  
0  [K3, 3.6666666666666665, 3, long-text, paragra...  
1  [P2, 3.5, 2, text, more-text, [(site7, 1), (si...  
2            [i7, 1.0, 1, review-text, [(site4, 1)]]
```

Comment: Incredible response time, and it gives me what I'm after! Thanks a bunch, seems so simple now

Comment: Another question: What if I want to create a field where all of the sources (with a count of each) are added to a list in a single column... Would this be possible? E.g. |K3|3.66|3|longtext...|[(Site1,1),(Site3,1),(Site5,1)] where the first part of the tuple (or dict) is the site name, and the second would be the number of reviews from that site on that product

Comment: give me a second.

Comment: maybe `[]` with Counter can be omit, it depends on what you need.